# SQL complicated select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a SELECT statement, but I am not really sure how to accomplish it.

I have 2 tables, `user` and `group`. Each user has a `userid` and each group has a `ownerid` that specifies who owns the group. Each group also has a `name` and then inside the user table, there is a column `group` designating which group that person belongs to. (excuse the annoying structure, I did not create it). I am trying to find all rows in `group` where the `ownerid` of that group does not have `group` (inside the user table) set to the `name` of that group. If this helps:

**User**

```
|-----------------------|  
| id | username | group |  
|----|----------|-------|  
|  0 | Steve    | night |  
|  1 | Sally    | night |  
|  2 | Susan    | sun   |  
|  3 | David    | xray  |
|-----------------------|
```

**Group**

```
|---------------------|  
| ownerid | name      |
|---------|-----------|
|  1      | night     | 
|  3      | bravo     |
|  2      | sun       |
|---------------------|
```

Where the SQL statement would return the group row for `bravo` because bravo's owner does not have his group set to bravo.

Comment: Where is your bash at a SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a join back to the original table and then a comparison of the values:

```
select g.*
from group g join
     user u
     on g.ownerid = id
where g.name <> u.group;
```

If the values can be `NULL`, then the logic would need to take that into account.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, but for some reason MySQL workbench is telling me that the output rows are read only. (I am assuming is has something to do with assigning group the name g?) Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: @user2249516 . . . I am not familiar with all the reasons why MySQL workbench would say the output is read-only.  One reason is the lack of primary key on a table.  Does `group` have a primary key?

Comment: Yeah, it does. I just had to copy the output, turn it into an array, then do it from there since I never figured out why it was read only. Thanks for the help though, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

An anti-join is a familiar pattern:

```
 SELECT g.*
   FROM `Group` g
   LEFT
   JOIN `User` u 
     ON u.group = g.name
    AND u.id = g.ownerid
  WHERE u.id IS NULL
```

Let's unpack that a bit.  We're going to start with returning all rows from Group. Then, we're going to "match" each row in Group with a row (or rows) from User. To be considered a "match", the `User.id` has to match the `Group.ownerid`, and the `User.group` value has to match the `Group.name`.

The "trick" is to eliminate all rows where we found a match (that's what the WHERE clause does), and that leaves us with only those rows from `Group` that didn't have a match.

Another way to obtain an equivalent result using a NOT EXISTS predicate

```
SELECT g.*
  FROM `Group` g
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1 
           FROM `User` u
          WHERE u.group = g.name 
            AND u.id = g.ownerid  
       )
```

This is uses a correlated subquery; it usually doesn't perform as fast as a join.

Note that these have the potential to return a slightly different result than the query from Gordon Linoff, if you had a row with in Group that had an ownerid value that wasn't in the user table.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT G.*
 FROM Group AS G
 WHERE G.Name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT U.Group FROM User AS U)
```